# Рисование изогнутых линий cо стрелками SVG от одного div к другому div

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, анимация

Я хочу нарисовать две изогнутые линии со стрелками, используя SVG, чтобы соединить два элемента, чтобы показать, что линии идут вперед и назад, вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я немного читал о SVG, но я не совсем уверен, как создать кривые линии.

Во-вторых, если SVG принимает координаты, мне нужно найти координаты элементов перед созданием чертежа SVG?

Должен ли чертёж быть перерисован, если размер окна будет изменен?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/39553105/7394871

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Создайте элемент SVG, который  лежит в основе всего документа.

Это будет удерживать обе стрелки внутри SVG. Добавьте два элемента пути SVG (стрелки), чьи начальные и конечные координаты рассчитываются на основе положений подключаемых элементов `div`, и форма кривых создается так, как вы хотите на основе этих начальных и конечных координат.

Для примера ниже, нажмите <kbd>Выполнить код</kbd>. Затем щелкните и перетащите любой из элементов `div`, чтобы увидеть, как стрелки изменяются динамически, то есть они перемещаются вместе с элементами `div`. jQuery и jQueryUI используются в фрагменте кода просто для упрощения перетаскивания элементов `div` и не имеют ничего общего с созданием и использованием стрелок.

В этом примере две стрелки начинаются и заканчиваются в середине сторон `div`.
Форма кривой, конечно, зависит от вас.

Стрелки построены с использованием атрибута `d` `path` SVG. В этом примере `M` - это координаты `moveTo`, с которых начнется траектория, а точки `C` - это первая и вторая контрольные точки и конечные координаты для кубической кривой Безье.

Вам придется изучить теорию, чтобы понять, что они из себя представляют, но это общий способ создания [плавных кривых](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) в элементе SVG.

Стрелки добавляются с использованием элемента SVG `<marker>`, о котором вы можете прочитать [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=855).

Более сложный документ потребует большей точности для определения начальной и конечной координат элементов пути SVG, то есть стрелок, но этот пример, по крайней мере, дает вам место для начала.

*Ответы на ваши конкретные вопросы:*

- Если SVG принимает координаты, должен ли я найти координатную позицию
  элементов перед созданием чертежа SVG? Да, как я сделал в своем коде.
- Должен ли чертёж быть перерисован, если размер окна изменён?
  Вероятно, да, в зависимости от того, что происходит с самими
  элементами div при изменении размера окна.

```js
var divA       = document.querySelector("#a");
var divB       = document.querySelector("#b");
var arrowLeft  = document.querySelector("#arrowLeft");
var arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrowRight");

var drawConnector = function() {
  var posnALeft = {
    x: divA.offsetLeft - 8,
    y: divA.offsetTop  + divA.offsetHeight / 2
  };
  var posnARight = {
    x: divA.offsetLeft + divA.offsetWidth + 8,
    y: divA.offsetTop  + divA.offsetHeight / 2    
  };
  var posnBLeft = {
    x: divB.offsetLeft - 8,
    y: divB.offsetTop  + divA.offsetHeight / 2
  };
  var posnBRight = {
    x: divB.offsetLeft + divB.offsetWidth + 8,
    y: divB.offsetTop  + divA.offsetHeight / 2
  };
  var dStrLeft =
      "M" +
      (posnALeft.x      ) + "," + (posnALeft.y) + " " +
      "C" +
      (posnALeft.x - 100) + "," + (posnALeft.y) + " " +
      (posnBLeft.x - 100) + "," + (posnBLeft.y) + " " +
      (posnBLeft.x      ) + "," + (posnBLeft.y);
  arrowLeft.setAttribute("d", dStrLeft);
  var dStrRight =
      "M" +
      (posnBRight.x      ) + "," + (posnBRight.y) + " " +
      "C" +
      (posnBRight.x + 100) + "," + (posnBRight.y) + " " +
      (posnARight.x + 100) + "," + (posnARight.y) + " " +
      (posnARight.x      ) + "," + (posnARight.y);
  arrowRight.setAttribute("d", dStrRight);
};

$("#a, #b").draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    drawConnector();
  }
});

setTimeout(drawConnector, 250);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#instructions {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
}
#a, #b {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 100px;
}
#a {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 20px;
}
#b {
  background-color: red;
  top: 180px;
}
```

```html
<p id="instructions">Нажмите и перетащите любой div, чтобы увидеть непроизвольную установку стрелок.</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrowhead" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="3" refY="5"
        markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" marker-end="url(#arrowhead)">
    <path id="arrowLeft"/>
    <path id="arrowRight"/>
  </g>
</svg>
<div id="a">Div 1</div>
<div id="b">Div 2</div>
```

**Update  26.01.2019 г.**

Ошибка при работе в полно-экранном режиме устранена при использовании совета @Bharata. Выражаю благодарность за помощь.

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39575674/7394871) от участника  [@Andrew Willems](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5218951/andrew-willems).</sub>

Comment: какая то лажа в полноэкранном просмотре

Comment: Благо дарю за перевод! Такое мне очень нравится. И всё работает отлично без изъянов!

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, такими гневными и безосновательными отзывами вы не сыщете себе здесь друзей! Пожалуйста, будьте вежливей и цените труд других пользователей! Если у вас возникают какие-то трудности, то пишите подробное описание ошибки. Я советую вам удалить свой отзыв и написать новый.

Comment: @Bharata да нормально всё у Павла :)  деффект есть. Я заметил это, только после его комментария. Если сразу открыть сниппет на полное окно идёт разрыв линий. Но если повозить дивы в свёрнутом окне, а потом развернуть сниппет на полную, то будет всё нормально! Изучаю сейчас, как это исправить

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, даже если и есть эта ошибка, то это не основание для того чтобы себя так вести и оставлять столь неуважительные отзывы. Я уверен, что Павлу бы не понравилось, если бы кто-то под его ответом написал такое.

Comment: @Bharata вполне возможно

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я про этого и говорил но Вы же понимаете что я не русский и мне скидка 90% ..простите если я выразился резко ...

Comment: @Bharata  https://www.dropbox.com/s/9khm5sasjdte8lp/2019-01-26_143750.png

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, ошибку эту исправить просто: замените `#b {bottom: 20px;}` на `#b {top: 180px;}` и всё будет работать правильно.

Comment: @Bharata  Благо дарю :)