# Как расширить регион действия клика

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, svg

Допустим имеем структурную схему проекта или схему БД, на которой прямоугольники, изображающие объекты, соединены линиями. Которые в свою очередь выполняют роль ссылок.

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
#line {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:1;
}
#line:hover {
stroke:red;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
    <rect x="10" y="40" width="100" height="50" rx="10" fill="skyblue" /> 
  <rect x="280" y="140" width="100" height="50" rx="10" fill="purple" />
   <a class="link" href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936744/28748"> 
 <polyline id="line"  points="110, 65 200,65 200,165 280 165" />
   </a> 
</svg>
```

**Одно из требований,- толщина линии-ссылки не должны превышать `1px`**

Но при достаточно большой схеме, в результате масштабирования `SVG` реально эти линии становятся ещё тоньше. Поэтому довольно проблематично попасть курсором в линию-ссылку.

Как расширить регион действия клика курсора мышки, допустим до `10px` в толщину, но при этом видимая толщина  линии не должна превышать `1px`

Принимается любое решение css, svg

**Напрашивается решение, лежащее на поверхности,- с двумя  линиями, но желательно использовать только одну линию.**

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, к сожалению это неверное решение. Нужно с обоих сторон от линии по 10px. А у вас, если вы замените свой fill на fill:#000, то увидите где ваши границы. Благо дарю за старания! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Готово, так подходит?

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
#line-transparent {
  fill: none;
  stroke: transparent;
  stroke-width: 10px;
}
#line-transparent:hover {
  stroke: transparent;
}
#line-transparent + #line {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:1;
}
#line-transparent:hover + #line,
#line-transparent + #line:hover {
stroke:red;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
    <rect x="10" y="40" width="100" height="50" rx="10" fill="skyblue" /> 
    <rect x="280" y="140" width="100" height="50" rx="10" fill="purple" />
  <a class="link" href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936744/28748"> 
    <polyline id="line-transparent"  points="110, 65 200,65 200,165 280 165" />
    <polyline id="line"  points="110, 65 200,65 200,165 280 165" />
  </a> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

### #1

Чтобы ширина линии не менялась при масштабировании SVG (изменении области просмотра) в SVG есть свойство, которое обеспечивает постоянную толщину линии при изменении масштаба.

[vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect)

**Идея решения с одной линией:**

Использовать две линии, одна видимая толщиной `1px`, а под ней невидимая, более широкая, которая становится видимой при наведении

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;

}
#line1 {
fill:none;
stroke:transparent;
stroke-width:10;


}
#line1:hover {
stroke:crimson; 

}
#line2 {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:1;
pointer-events:none;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 400 400"  >  
    <rect x="10" y="40" width="100" height="50" rx="10" fill="skyblue" /> 
  <rect x="280" y="140" width="100" height="50" rx="10" fill="purple" />
   <a class="link" href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936744/28748"> 
 <polyline id="line1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" points="110, 65 200,65 200,165 280 165"  />
 <polyline id="line2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" points="110, 65 200,65 200,165 280 165" />
   </a> 
</svg> 
</div>
```

### #2 Анимация увеличение толщины линии

**Идея решения:**

Используется одна линия, при наведении на неё происходит анимация расширения толщины до `10px`, облегчая тем самым попадание курсора для клика.

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
#line {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:1;
transition:  ease-out 0.3s;
}
#line:hover {
stroke-width:10;
stroke:gray;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
    <rect x="10" y="40" width="100" height="50" rx="10" fill="skyblue" /> 
  <rect x="280" y="140" width="100" height="50" rx="10" fill="purple" />
   <a class="link" href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936744/28748"> 
 <polyline id="line"  points="110, 65 200,65 200,165 280 165" />
   </a> 
</svg>
```